# Flex Mobile Handling XML Data

Tags: apache-flex, mobile

I am venturing development on mobile apps using Flex.

I am trying to use HttpService to connect to a url which returns an XML data.

```
<s:HttpService id="test" url="UrlToConnectTo" />
```

And in the script:

```
private function init() :void
{
  test.send();
}
```

And the lastResult of the service I am binding to a List..

```
<s:List id="list" top="0" bottom="0" left="0" right="0"
  dataProvider="{test.lastResult.Item.FiscalYear }" 
        labelField="ItemDescription"/>
```

Are there other alternate means of handling data returned by services? I would like to inspect the data, but I am not sure what type of data it is after being bound to the list (array, arraycollection??).

Side Note:
I can also get the data via JSON, but I am unable to bind the data retrieved properly to the list control.

Appreciate any links / insights provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Are there other alternate means of handling data returned by services?
```

Yes,s, use a [result event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html#event%3aresult) handler.  Conceptually something like this:

```
<s:HttpService id="test" url="UrlToConnectTo" result="onResult(event)" />
```

And your handler method:

```
protected function onResult(event:ResultEvent):void{
  trace(event.result);
  // convert XML result to XMLListCollection
  var myCollection : XMLListCollection = new XMLListCollection(event.result as XML);
  // convert array result to ARrayCollection
  var myCollection : ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(event.result as Array);
}
```

Most likely you'll want to convert your data from whatever is returned into something more useful in Flex.  XML to an XMLList or an Array to an ArrayCollection, as two examples.

Comment: Can you modify your answer to provide example, if say, data returned is XML or JSON? How would I be able to cast it to XML (XMLList) or Array (ArrayCollection)?

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize I had improperly formatted my result handler, I fixed that.  You won't be able to cast JSON into XML or an ArrayCollection as far as I know.  You'll have to run them through some kind of conversion.  You should be able to create a new XMLListCollection with your XML as the source though.  I'll update my question.

Comment: It would really be helpful if JSON returned collection can be cast to another data type. I would test the one you provided later and see how it goes.

Comment: I haven't had to deal with JSON, so I'm not sure how it's implemented under the hood; but it seems feasible that you could create a JSONCollection class, similar to an ArrayCollection or XMLListCollection.

Comment: I tried the code for the XML, but the XML variable I used simply returns null. I know that the data is there, because the list still displays the items as per binding with the test.lastResult.Item.FiscalYear in the dataProvider.

I think I read somewhere that in mobile apps, the ResultHandler does not necessarily contain the data from the requested URL, but rather, the resultHandler simply invokes whether the operation was successful.

Comment: Do you have a source for the claim that in mobile apps the resultHandler does not contain data from the service call?  That is news to me and contrary to my personal experience.

Comment: I was able to get it working. Thanks for your input. I modified a part of your answer to make it the right answer.

Comment: @batula IF there is something wrong w/ my posted answer, please share the corrected code and I can edit my answer to be more accurate.